# Why is drupal 8 not rendering html in my custom block?

Tags: html, drupal, drupal-8

I am trying to add a site map to the bottom of my page in the footer blocks section.  So I have added html to a custom block

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href='some/section'>section</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

but when I view the source it is not taking it in as html even though I have the input type as full html.  the above code turns into

```
&lt;ul&gt;
  &lt;li&gt;
    &lt;a href='some/section'&gt; section &lt;/a&gt;
  &lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
```

Why?  What setting could be doing this?  I have tried every html input type out of the box with drupal8 but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the text editor by clicking the "source" button on the right side of the the editor menu it has allowed html and does not try to convert my code to text